# How to reference the same column from 2 seperate IDs SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, nested

I've been looking around for a bit unable to find an answer to this that works, So, I'm hoping someone can help me with my best bet to solve this. Basically I have a table with a User_id and a delegate_id, however both obviously reference the same user_mstr table. But what I want is the name of both the user and the delegate.

Here is the part of my query in question:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, delegate_user_id, delegate_provider_ind, 
       tasks_ind, workflow_use_always_ind
FROM workflow_user_delegates ud
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mstr u ON ud.user_id=u.user_id
```

But I want the delegate_id to be changed into a name, except obviously I already referenced user first and last name.

The exact software is SQL Server 2008. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to all those that helped! Surprised the answer was fairly simple, yet still couldn't get it to work for me.

Comment: Glad we were able to help. Please mark as accepted the answer that best helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.first_name AS user_first_name, u.last_name AS user_last_name, 
       d.first_name AS delegate_first_name, d.last_name AS delegate_last_name, 
       delegate_user_id, delegate_provider_ind, 
       tasks_ind, workflow_use_always_ind
FROM workflow_user_delegates ud
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mstr u ON ud.user_id=u.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mstr d ON ud.delegate_user_id=d.user_id
```

Comment: good catch, was just about to point out that your second join was referencing `u.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table twice, just provide different aliases for the table.  Something like this:

```
....
FROM workflow_user_delegates ud
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mstr u ON ud.user_id=u.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mstr d ON ud.delegate_id=d.user_id
```

So any references to `u.[...]` in the `SELECT` will reference the one joined based on `user_id`, and any references to `d.[...]` will reference the one based on `delegate_id`.

---

To differentiate the columns in the `SELECT` clause, use a similar approach for aliasing.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    ....
    u.first_name AS user_first_name,
    u.last_name AS user_last_name,
    d.first_name AS delegate_first_name,
    d.last_name AS delegate_last_name,
    ....
```

Comment: second join should reference `d.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alias = expression` or `expression AS alias` to alias column names.

```
select 
    u.first_name
  , u.last_name
  , delegate_user_id
  , delegate_first_name = d.first_name
  , delegate_last_name = d.lastname
  , delegate_provider_ind
  , tasks_ind
  , workflow_use_always_ind
from workflow_user_delegates ud
  left join user_mstr u on ud.user_id = u.user_id
  left join user_mstr d on ud.delegate_user_id = d.user_id
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much